# Is it possible to share variables between a node.js file and html/javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, p5.js

I'm doing a project consisting of two parts. One part is javascript/html and uses a CDN-hosted pose-estimation library ([ml5](https://unpkg.com/ml5@0.1.3/dist/ml5.min.js)) along with p5.js. The other part is Node.JS and uses an npm-installed library ([osc.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/osc)). I would like to take variables from the hosted/html section and pass them to the Node.JS project. How can I do this?

I've tried downloading and adapting the ml5 library and including it in my node project, but I've had no luck with this as it is designed for the browser.

My HTML file:

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@0.1.3/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
      ...and so on....
```

My associated javascript file (exerpt), using the ml5 library:

```
let video;
let poseNet;
let noseX = 0;

function setup() {
  // some setup code here
  poseNet = ml5.poseNet(video, modelReady);
}

function gotPoses(poses) {
  if (poses.length > 0) {
    let noseY = poses[0].pose.keypoints[0].position.x;
  }
}
```

My Node.JS file (which sends data over OSC/UDP), uses the node library OSC:

```
var osc = require("osc");

// some code here

setInterval(function() {
    var msg = {
        address: "/hello/from/oscjs",
        args: [
            {
                type: "s",
                value: noseY
            }
        ]
    };

// more code here
```

I would like to be able to call the noseY variable from within the Node.JS file, but I see no way to grab it from the html/javascript section. There exists a ml5 package for npm, but it is still under development and doesn't work for me. I have also looked for browser-based alternatives to the OSC library, but could not find any suitable alternatives.

Comment: Have you looked into Sockets? https://socket.io/

Comment: If both files are hosted on the same server why don't you just read the file using standard file functions?

Comment: The js file which uses the ml5 library is not hosted on the node server as it needs to access the CDN library through <script> tag.

Comment: Socket.io solved this problem.